# Modify AVR audioplayer code to play random track

Tags: c, sd-card, avr

I have been playing around with ATtiny's and arduino for a while but am a complete newbee in 'real' AVR programming.
I am building a laser gun and target for my son and want to have the target play a random silly animal sound whenever it is hit. 
The other functions of the target is maintained by Attiny85s and i therefore stumbled upon Elm-Chans code for interfacing a microSD card with Attiny85 and play .wav files by PWM. 
However the code is written so that it plays files on the SD card root folder (or other dir) in order and skips to next in response to a pushbutton on one of the pins.
What i want it to do is to pick and play a random file from the root when button is pushed (i.e. target is hit). 
It should play the sound only once and preferably interrupt an already playing file and play another if the target is hit again before the sound has ended.
I have been trying really hard to figure out what to change in the code but come to realize that i need to start from the beginning with learning AVR programming from scratch...however that will take some time and before i get there i humbly hope that any of you could grant me a quick fix and tell me what to do, so i can finish the toy.
Kind regards
Mads

```
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------/
/  8-pin SD audio player R0.05d                    (C)ChaN, 2011              /
/-----------------------------------------------------------------------------/
/ This project, program codes and circuit diagrams, is opened under license
/ policy of following trems.
/
/  Copyright (C) 2010, ChaN, all right reserved.
/
/ * This project is a free software and there is NO WARRANTY.
/ * No restriction on use. You can use, modify and redistribute it for
/   personal, non-profit or commercial use UNDER YOUR RESPONSIBILITY.
/ * Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice.
/
/----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <avr/sleep.h>
#include <avr/wdt.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "pff.h"
#include "xitoa.h"

#ifndef MODE
#error Wrong make file.
#endif
#if   MODE == 0 /* Single output */
FUSES = {0xE1, 0xDD, 0xFF}; /* Fuse bytes for mono: Low, High and Extended */
#else           /* Dual output */
FUSES = {0xE1, 0x7D, 0xFF}; /* Fuse bytes for stereo and mono-HR: Low, High and Extended (*HVS mode only*) */
#endif
/* This is the fuse settings of this project. The fuse data will be included
in the output hex file with program code. However some old flash programmers
cannot load the fuse bits from hex file. If it is the case, remove this line
and use these values to program the fuse bits. */


#define FCC(c1,c2,c3,c4)    (((DWORD)c4<<24)+((DWORD)c3<<16)+((WORD)c2<<8)+(BYTE)c1)    /* FourCC */

void delay_us (WORD);   /* Defined in asmfunc.S */



/*---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Work Area                                               */
/*---------------------------------------------------------*/

volatile BYTE FifoRi, FifoWi, FifoCt;   /* FIFO controls */

BYTE Buff[256];     /* Wave output FIFO */

FATFS Fs;           /* File system object */
DIR Dir;            /* Directory object */
FILINFO Fno;        /* File information */

WORD rb;            /* Return value. Put this here to avoid avr-gcc's bug */



/*---------------------------------------------------------*/

static
DWORD load_header (void)    /* 0:Invalid format, 1:I/O error, >=1024:Number of samples */
{
    DWORD sz, f;
    BYTE b, al = 0;


    if (pf_read(Buff, 12, &rb)) return 1;   /* Load file header (12 bytes) */

    if (rb != 12 || LD_DWORD(Buff+8) != FCC('W','A','V','E')) return 0;

    for (;;) {
        wdt_reset();
        pf_read(Buff, 8, &rb);          /* Get Chunk ID and size */
        if (rb != 8) return 0;
        sz = LD_DWORD(&Buff[4]);        /* Chunk size */

        switch (LD_DWORD(&Buff[0])) {   /* Switch by chunk ID */
        case FCC('f','m','t',' ') :                 /* 'fmt ' chunk */
            if (sz & 1) sz++;                       /* Align chunk size */
            if (sz > 100 || sz < 16) return 0;      /* Check chunk size */
            pf_read(Buff, sz, &rb);                 /* Get content */
            if (rb != sz) return 0;
            if (Buff[0] != 1) return 0;             /* Check coding type (LPCM) */
            b = Buff[2];
            if (b != 1 && b != 2) return 0;         /* Check channels (1/2) */
            GPIOR0 = al = b;                        /* Save channel flag */
            b = Buff[14];
            if (b != 8 && b != 16) return 0;        /* Check resolution (8/16 bit) */
            GPIOR0 |= b;                            /* Save resolution flag */
            if (b & 16) al <<= 1;
            f = LD_DWORD(&Buff[4]);                 /* Check sampling freqency (8k-48k) */
            if (f < 8000 || f > 48000) return 4;
            OCR0A = (BYTE)(F_CPU / 8 / f) - 1;      /* Set sampling interval */
            break;

        case FCC('d','a','t','a') :     /* 'data' chunk */
            if (!al) return 0;                          /* Check if format is valid */
            if (sz < 1024 || (sz & (al - 1))) return 0; /* Check size */
            if (Fs.fptr & (al - 1)) return 0;           /* Check word alignment */
            return sz;                                  /* Start to play */

        case FCC('D','I','S','P') :     /* 'DISP' chunk */
        case FCC('L','I','S','T') :     /* 'LIST' chunk */
        case FCC('f','a','c','t') :     /* 'fact' chunk */
            if (sz & 1) sz++;               /* Align chunk size */
            pf_lseek(Fs.fptr + sz);         /* Skip this chunk */
            break;

        default :                       /* Unknown chunk */
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}



static
void ramp (
    int dir     /* 0:Ramp-down, 1:Ramp-up */
)
{
#if MODE != 3
    BYTE v, d, n;


    if (dir) {
        v = 0; d = 1;
    } else {
        v = 128; d = (BYTE)-1;
    }

    n = 128;
    do {
        v += d;
        OCR1A = v; OCR1B = v;
        delay_us(100);
    } while (--n);
#else
    dir = dir ? 128 : 0;
    OCR1A = (BYTE)dir; OCR1B = (BYTE)dir;
#endif
}



static
FRESULT play (
    const char *dir,    /* Directory */
    const char *fn      /* File */
)
{
    DWORD sz;
    FRESULT res;
    BYTE sw;
    WORD btr;


    wdt_reset();

    xsprintf((char*)Buff, PSTR("%s/%s"), dir, fn);
    res = pf_open((char*)Buff);     /* Open sound file */
    if (res == FR_OK) {
        sz = load_header();         /* Check file format and ready to play */
        if (sz < 1024) return 255;  /* Cannot play this file */

        FifoCt = 0; FifoRi = 0; FifoWi = 0; /* Reset audio FIFO */

        if (!TCCR1) {               /* Enable audio out if not enabled */
            PLLCSR = 0b00000110;    /* Select PLL clock for TC1.ck */
            GTCCR =  0b01100000;    /* Enable OC1B as PWM */
            TCCR1 = MODE ? 0b01100001 : 0b00000001; /* Start TC1 and enable OC1A as PWM if needed */
            TCCR0A = 0b00000010;    /* Statr TC0 as interval timer at 2MHz */
            TCCR0B = 0b00000010;
            TIMSK = _BV(OCIE0A);
            ramp(1);
        }

        pf_read(0, 512 - (Fs.fptr % 512), &rb); /* Snip sector unaligned part */
        sz -= rb;
        sw = 1; /* Button status flag */
        do {    /* Data transfer loop */
            wdt_reset();

            btr = (sz > 1024) ? 1024 : (WORD)sz;/* A chunk of audio data */
            res = pf_read(0, btr, &rb); /* Forward the data into audio FIFO */
            if (rb != 1024) break;      /* Break on error or end of data */
            sz -= rb;                   /* Decrease data counter */

            sw <<= 1;                   /* Break on button down */
        } while ((PINB & 1) || ++sw != 1);
    }

    while (FifoCt) ;            /* Wait for audio FIFO empty */
    OCR1A = 128; OCR1B = 128;   /* Return output to center level */

    return res;
}



static
void delay500 (void)
{
    wdt_reset();

    TCCR0B = 0; TCCR0A = 0; /* Stop TC0 */

    if (TCCR1) {    /* Stop TC1 if enabled */
        ramp(0);
        TCCR1 = 0; GTCCR = 0;
    }

    WDTCR = _BV(WDE) | _BV(WDIE) | 0b101;   /* Set WDT to interrupt mode in timeout of 0.5s */
    set_sleep_mode(SLEEP_MODE_PWR_DOWN);    /* Enter power down mode */
    sleep_mode();

    wdt_reset();
    WDTCR = _BV(WDE) | 0b110;               /* Set WDT to reset mode in timeout of 1s */
}


EMPTY_INTERRUPT(WDT_vect);



/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Main                                                                  */

int main (void)
{
    FRESULT res;
    char *dir;
    BYTE org_osc = OSCCAL;


    MCUSR = 0;
    WDTCR = _BV(WDE) | 0b110;   /* Enable WDT reset in timeout of 1s */

    PORTB = 0b101001;       /* Initialize port: - - H L H L L P */
    DDRB  = 0b111110;

    sei();

    for (;;) {
        if (pf_mount(&Fs) == FR_OK) {   /* Initialize FS */
            wdt_reset();
            Buff[0] = 0;
            if (!pf_open("osccal")) pf_read(Buff, 1, &rb);  /* Adjust frequency */
            OSCCAL = org_osc + Buff[0];

            res = pf_opendir(&Dir, dir = "wav");    /* Open sound file directory */
            if (res == FR_NO_PATH)
                res = pf_opendir(&Dir, dir = "");   /* Open root directory */

            while (res == FR_OK) {              /* Repeat in the dir */
                res = pf_readdir(&Dir, 0);          /* Rewind dir */
                while (res == FR_OK) {              /* Play all wav files in the dir */
                    wdt_reset();
                    res = pf_readdir(&Dir, &Fno);       /* Get a dir entry */
                    if (res || !Fno.fname[0]) break;    /* Break on error or end of dir */
                    if (!(Fno.fattrib & (AM_DIR|AM_HID)) && strstr(Fno.fname, ".WAV"))
                        res = play(dir, Fno.fname);     /* Play file */
                }
            }
        }
        delay500();         /* Delay 500ms in low power sleep mode */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I reckon your case requires more C-coding knowledge than AVR-hacking one.

Here:

```
if (!(Fno.fattrib & (AM_DIR|AM_HID)) && strstr(Fno.fname, ".WAV"))
      res = play(dir, Fno.fname);     /* Play file */
```

Every time matching file is found, play function is called. What you want instead is to add this file descriptor to some form of container (e.g. list) of available files. After all files are listed, you may want to wait for external input (hit by laser), and then play the file and move current file index to the next.
To enable pausing and resetting playback, I recommend using external interrupt for handling "on hit" events.

PS Building toys for your kid using AVR? +1 from me!

Comment: Hi Kissiel...thanx for your answer and moral support :-). I get your drift, but unfortunately my skills do not suffice to implement them. But am i right in assuming that your suggestion is to load a single given file to ram before "hit" interrupt and then have interrupt routine play the file and also load another file based on some shift in card content indexing?